# PHP eBay Trading API AddItems call returns 'Invalid job context type' error

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

I'm trying to list an item on eBay with the eBay Trading API using PHP and CURL

Everything (XML and my script) looks OK or I just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

This is my **request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>  
<AddItemRequestContainer>  
<MessageID>100</MessageID>  
<Item>  
<BuyItNowPrice>238.00</BuyItNowPrice>  
<CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>  
<ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>  
<Country>CA</Country>  
<Currency>CAD</Currency>  
<Title>TEST</Title>  
<Description>DEscription</Description>  
<DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>  
<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>  
<ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>  
<PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>  
<PayPalEmailAddress>paypal@jccayer.com</PayPalEmailAddress>  
<PictureDetails>  
<Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>  
http://www.jccayer.com/productphoto/2793-22-1_ep1.jpg  
</Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>  
<PictureURL>http://www.jccayer.com/productphoto/2793-22-1_ep1.jpg</PictureURL>  
</PictureDetails>  
<PostalCode>K0A1M0</PostalCode>  
<PrimaryCategory>  
<CategoryID>279</CategoryID>  
</PrimaryCategory>  
<Quantity>1</Quantity>  
<ReturnPolicy>  
<ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>  
<RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>  
<ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>  
<Description>Text description of return policy details</Description>  
<ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>  
</ReturnPolicy>  
<ShippingDetails>  
<ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>  
<ShippingServiceOptions>  
<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>  
<ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardCanada</ShippingService>  
<ShippingServiceCost>21.50</ShippingServiceCost>  
</ShippingServiceOptions>  
</ShippingDetails>  
<Site>Canada</Site>  
<UUID>4d8b04a3ae054a978a66848fafd524c9</UUID>  
</Item>  
</AddItemRequestContainer>  
<RequesterCredentials>  
<eBayAuthToken>[INSERT YOUR OWN AUTH TOKEN]</eBayAuthToken>  
</RequesterCredentials>  
</AddItemsRequest>
```

**Response:**

```
Array
(
[Timestamp] => 2013-08-22T13:16:02.397Z
[Ack] => Failure
[Errors] => Array
    (
        [ShortMessage] => Invalid job context type
        [LongMessage] => The job context object is not supported by Action Service Framework.
        [ErrorCode] => 21843
        [SeverityCode] => Error
        [ErrorParameters] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [ParamID] => 0
                            )

                        [Value] => AddItem
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [ParamID] => 1
                            )

                        [Value] => AddItemsRequestType
                    )

            )

        [ErrorClassification] => RequestError
    )

[Version] => 833
[Build] => E833_UNI_API5_16246498_R1
)
```

Anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

---

## Edit

As i got the answer from David T. Sadler he advised me to try to use `StartingPrice` instead of `BuyItNowPrice`

So that is what I did. Also David said he was able to run my XML through the API testing tool. When I tried it, it did not work over there either.

Here is my new request

**Headers**

```
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:833
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:76803363-a07b-4c24-b5c7-f38ce3dd1ba7
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:JeanClau-bd2d-4e64-9466-41fbecfb8bb6
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:4624a573-0320-4604-ac18-f7fc07d0ea8b
X-EBAY-API-SITEID:2
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:AddItem
```

**XML Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AddItemsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">  
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>    
<AddItemRequestContainer>    
<MessageID>100</MessageID>    
<Item>    
<StartingPrice>238.00</StartingPrice>    
<CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>    
<ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>    
<Country>CA</Country>    
<Currency>CAD</Currency>    
<Title>TEST</Title>    
<Description>DEscription</Description>    
<DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>    
<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>    
<ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>    
<PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>    
<PayPalEmailAddress>paypal@jccayer.com</PayPalEmailAddress>    
<PictureDetails>    
<Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>    
http://www.jccayer.com/productphoto/2793-22-1_ep1.jpg    
</Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>    
<PictureURL>http://www.jccayer.com/productphoto/2793-22-1_ep1.jpg</PictureURL>    
</PictureDetails>    
<PostalCode>K0A1M0</PostalCode>    
<PrimaryCategory>    
<CategoryID>279</CategoryID>    
</PrimaryCategory>    
<Quantity>1</Quantity>    
<ReturnPolicy>    
<ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>    
<RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>    
<ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>    
<Description>Text description of return policy details</Description>    
<ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>    
</ReturnPolicy>    
<ShippingDetails>    
<ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>    
<ShippingServiceOptions>    
<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>    
<ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardCanada</ShippingService>    
<ShippingServiceCost>21.50</ShippingServiceCost>    
</ShippingServiceOptions>    
</ShippingDetails>    
<Site>Canada</Site>    
<UUID>4d8b04a3ae054a978a66848fafd524c9</UUID>    
</Item>    
</AddItemRequestContainer>    
<RequesterCredentials>    
<eBayAuthToken>[INSERT YOUR OWN AUTH TOKEN]</eBayAuthToken>    
</RequesterCredentials>    
</AddItemsRequest>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<AddItemsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">  
  <Timestamp>2013-08-23T13:31:10.575Z</Timestamp>  
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>  
  <Errors>  
    <ShortMessage>Auth token is invalid.</ShortMessage>  
    <LongMessage>Validation of the authentication token in API request failed.</LongMessage>  
    <ErrorCode>931</ErrorCode>  
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>  
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>  
  </Errors>  
  <Version>833</Version>  
  <Build>E833_UNI_API5_16246498_R1</Build>  
</AddItemsResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your request is that the *BuyItNowPrice* element is not valid for a *FixedPriceItem* listing. You need to change it to *StartingPrice*. Other than that the request is fine. I've even copied and pasted your XML into the eBay API Test Tool and the item was listed. http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/110121707611

Without seeing how you are using PHP and Curl to send the request I can only recommend the following.

- Ensure that you are sending a POST request to the correct end point.

  - Sandbox: https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
  - Product: https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
- Problems can happen if there are space characters at the start of your request string. Ensure that the first character in this string is the XML request.
- Make sure that CURL sends the following HTTP headers with the correct values.

  - X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:833
  - X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:[REPLACE WITH YOUR DEVID]
  - X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:[REPLACE WITH YOUR APPID]
  - X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:[REPLACE WITH YOUR CERTID]
  - X-EBAY-API-SITEID:2
  - X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:AddItems

Comment: Thank you so much for you input.

but i just test it out, and it sill does the same.
From my understanding i had to change this element <BuyItNowPrice> to <FixedPriceItem>

is that corect ?

I looked at my header and sending it exsactly like you advice me

Comment: Thanks it was not startingPrice But StartPrice

but you made me realise thanks ! :)